# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts during ASP.net Azure deployment

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, azure

In my ASP.net Web App, I built a MySQL database using MySQL workbench and connected it to Azure through "Azure for MySQL Database" resource group.
The following is the connection string of the database written in Web.config

```
<add name ="AzureCon" connectionString="Server={myserver}; Port=3306; Database={mydatabase}; Uid={myuser}; Pwd={mypassword}; SslMode=Preferred;"/>
```

I call the connection string using the following code

```
string CoString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureCon"].ConnectionString;
```

However, when I publish the web app using Azure, the only error I get is:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: MySqlConnector.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

> Source Error:
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.]
   MySqlConnector.Core.<ConnectAsync>d__68.MoveNext() +1567
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +26
   MySqlConnector.Core.<GetSessionAsync>d__10.MoveNext() +2632
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +27
   MySqlConnector.Core.<GetSessionAsync>d__10.MoveNext() +3745
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() +121
   MySqlConnector.<CreateSessionAsync>d__115.MoveNext() +696
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   MySqlConnector.<OpenAsync>d__27.MoveNext() +977
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.Open() +61
   Hangfire.MySql.MySqlStorage.CreateAndOpenConnection() +49
   Hangfire.MySql.MySqlStorage..ctor(String connectionString, MySqlStorageOptions storageOptions) +140
   CoPro.<GetHangfireServers>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Users\smir\Desktop\Files and Folders\Programming\C#\CoPro\CoPro\Startup.cs:22
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +217
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +76
   Hangfire.HangfireAspNet.StartInstances(Func`1 configuration) +130
   Hangfire.HangfireAspNet.Use(Func`1 configuration) +13
   Hangfire.HangfireAspNet.UseHangfireAspNet(IAppBuilder builder, Func`1 configuration) +21
   CoPro.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in C:\Users\smir\Desktop\Files and Folders\Programming\C#\CoPro\CoPro\Startup.cs:37

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +168
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +105
   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass19_1.<MakeDelegate>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +66
   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<LoadImplementation>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +123
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<InitializeBlueprint>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +81
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +445
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +40
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +70
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +119
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +91
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +522
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +176
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +219
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +304

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +659
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +89
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189
```

I'm using **no** other database or connection.

As in Azure resource group, I have updated the Firewall security and added the "allow all" rule for all IPv4 addresses.

MySQL works fine locally.

Here's my firewall settings in the Azure Database for MySQL server

[image]

[image]

Here's the "Users and Privileges" tab in my connection in MySQL Workbench

[image]

***Note: The problem was there even before connecting MySQL to Azure***

Comment: Are you able to connect while debugging locally?

Comment: yes and it works fine

Comment: Just to eliminate any low hanging fruits, please confirm the connection string format: `Server={myserver}.mysql.database.azure.com; Port=3306; Database={mydatabase}; Uid={myuser}@{myserver}; Pwd={mypassword}; SslMode=Preferred;`

Comment: That's true. this is the string format. Every element you mentioned is placed correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks. Then I would imagine only a network restriction somewhere in your infrastructure can cause this. Either firewall (which you said you already allowed) or NSG rules. Another thing, can you **TEMPORARILY** log the connection string from code (`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureCon"].ConnectionString`) somewhere to verify it's correctly read after deployment.

Comment: I recently added a local DB to implement ASP.net identity, following these instructions [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project). It's working fine, giving no errors while deployment (considering that the error is for MySQL hosts and not SQL). This is defined in Web.config as well with a connection string. I replaced this string with the MySQL connection in the following code `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureCon"].ConnectionString` however, it gave the same error.

Comment: In short, by replacing the connection strings, I configured no connection to MySQL in any of my web forms. The connections are only to the LocalDB for the ASP.net identity which happens to be an SQL databse.

Comment: Ok. Then you confirm the config part is fine. So, my focus now shifts to the first point (network connectivity) or anything else related to DB. Connect to your Azure MySQL instance using the [MySQL Workbench](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/mysql/connect-workbench) and see if you can see the database {mydatabase} created there. (I assume you are not expecting the DB to be created automatically by asp.net identity)

Comment: That's right.I haven't got many possibilities and so i'm clinching my assumptions to less possibilities. I already connected Azure MySQL to the MySQL Workbench and the data's there. As you said, the focus is now on the network connectivity. I'm not sure, however, what the problem is specifically in the network connectivity

Comment: When publishing, the Publish Wizard says on the remote connection string of my MySQL connection "The Database provider for this connection string MySQL.Data.MySQLClient, is not supported for incremental database publishing.

Comment: That's fine. Ignore that publish warning for now. Regarding network part, can you please update the answer with screenshot of the firewall settings.

Comment: Done. I uploaded the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221343/discussion-between-amir-and-krishnendughosh-msft).

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: no it hasn't. I'm still waiting for some help and I did lots of research on it but haven't found a soltuion.

Comment: @Amir Can you provide your sample code (be careful to hide sensitive information)? Or which blog or tutorial did you follow? Generally speaking, this problem should not arise, because you have configured all the operations we can see now.

Comment: @Amir To help you better, we need sample code so that if the same problem occurs during deployment, we can troubleshoot.

Comment: Has this been solved?